# cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'project' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only

Tags: xml, apache-camel, pom.xml

I tried searching for the solution of this problem, with not much success. I also am a beginner at XML so pls bear with any matter of fact things missed out.

Here is my code for the pom.xml in my project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Camel Blueprint Quickstart</name>
  <description>Empty Camel Blueprint Example</description>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <properties>
    <camel.version>2.17.3</camel.version>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <version.maven-bundle-plugin>2.3.7</version.maven-bundle-plugin>
    <jboss.fuse.bom.version>6.3.0.redhat-187</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.8</version>
    </dependency>


      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  //REPOSITORIES
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  //PLUGIN REPOS
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>helloworldroute</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>Empty Camel Blueprint Example [helloworldroute]</Bundle-Name></instructions></configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments like

```
//REPOSITORIES
```

are not allowed by the schema.

Use XML comments instead:

```
<!--REPOSITORIES-->
```

Comment: @MichaelKay would you help me on [this.xml](https://imgur.com/a/euvAv)?

Comment: If you have a question, then please ask it in the normal way.

Comment: @MichaelKay I guess new question is not needed as the problem is related. view the image with error of  `this.xml` in previous comment.

Comment: That's not the way StackOverflow works. Comments are for comments, not for supplementary questions. And you should address them to the community at large, not to specific individuals.